# Powershell For IIS: 'Foreach' Loop Failing

Tags: powershell, iis-8, powershell-4.0

I needed to create a PowerShell that first builds 50 IIS App Pools and assign them each an App Pool Identity (username and password.) The next part of the script is to convert a sites child folders into Applications. During the conversion process, I must assign each Application to use the specific App Pool I created above. Here is my script that partially works.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration 

$AppPools = @ (“site1-app1”,”site1-app2”,”site1-app3”,”site1-app4”,”site1-app5”…”site1-app50”)
$AppPoolFolders = @ (“app1”,”app2”,”app3”,”app4”,”app5”…”app50”)

$username = ‘domain\Site1SvcAct’
$password = ‘Site1SvcActPassword’

########——Create App Pool and Set Username & Password——########


foreach ($App in $AppPools) {

New-WebAppPool $App
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$App managedPipelineMode 0
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$App managedRuntimeVersion v4.0
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$App -Name processmodel -value @{userName = $username;password=$password;identitytype=3}

########——Convert /folder to Application and set to use App Pool ——########

    foreach ($Folder in $AppPoolFolders) {

    ConvertTo-WebApplication -ApplicationPool $App -PSPath ‘IIS:\Sites\Site1\$Folder’

    }
}
```

The App Pools are created successfully with the correct App Pool Identity but the Application conversion partially works. The folders become child applications as expected but they do not run the correct App Pool Identities. It assigns all of the App Pool Folders the first App Pool.

```
app1 : site1-app1 
app2 : site1-app1
app3 : site1-app1
.
.
.
app50 : site1-app1
```

Where is should look like this:

```
app1 : site1-app1 
app2 : site1-app2
app3 : site1-app2
.
.
.
app50 : site1-app50
```

So Folder 1 should be assigned App Pool 1 and Folder 2 should be assigned App Pool 2 etc... I know this is because of my nested "foreach" loop but I do not know how to fix the loop to get my desired output. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can changed your nested for loops into a single for loop

So instead of using

`foreach($app in $apppools){
    foreach( $folder in $AppPoolsFolder){
    }
}`

You can use

`for( $i = 0; $i -lt $appPools.Count; $i++){
    $app = $appPools[$i]
    $Folder = $appPoolsFolder[$i]
    ...Rest of your code...
}`

Answer (score 0):

This line …

foreach ($Folder in $AppPoolFolders) {

ConvertTo-WebApplication -ApplicationPool $App -PSPath ‘IIS:\Sites\Site1\$Folder’

}

… is not correct.

You are using single quotes and thus no variable expansion.

Try that line this way ...

```
foreach ($Folder in $AppPoolFolders) {

ConvertTo-WebApplication -ApplicationPool $App -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\Site1\$($Folder)"

}
```

… Variables only get expanded using double quotes.